# Processing.js won't load script

Tags: javascript, processing.js

ANSWER: *******

For everybody else that overlook things:

After you done all the other things in Getting started section:

1. You have to cd in your processing.js directory and start the httpd.py
2. Go to 127.0.01:9914 or any other port you specificed there.
3. VOILA...It works.

Always read the readme :)
But I also have to say that a "Get started" Section should include this important detail.
Eventhough it might be obvious.

---

Hi I am trying to get processing.js running and it frustrates the.. out of me.
It couldnt be simpler, right:

http://processingjs.org/learning

**1. I have a myname.html with this:**

```
<script src="processing-js-1.3.6/processing-1.3.6.js"></script>   
<canvas data-processing-sources="myname.pde"></canvas>
```

(just if you wonder, I also tried to add DOCTYPE, body, html, everything html needs, did not work)

**2. And this is in my myname.pde:**

```
void setup()  
{  
  size(200,200);  
  background(125);  
  fill(255);  
  noLoop();  
  PFont fontA = loadFont("courier");  
  textFont(fontA, 14);    
}  

void draw(){    
  text("Hello Web!",20,20);  
  println("Hello ErrorLog!");  
}
```

All from the starter example (!!!). 
I have the whole processing.js folder in the same directory.
If I load the example.html in it works.

If I hit my starter example it wont load.
At this point I really dont know what I did wrong. 
It seems supereasy straight forward but it doesnt work.

Do I have to change something in the http conf ?
Do I have to add anything in the code ?
Is it the Browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I have the whole processing.js folder in the same directory. If I load
>   the example.html in it works."

Yet, in your html in seems that you're calling the two files as if they're located in different directories:

```
<script src="processing-js-1.3.6/processing-1.3.6.js"></script>   
<canvas data-processing-sources="myname.pde"></canvas>
```

It is looking for the processing-1.3.6.js file in the processing-1.3.6.js directory and loading the myname.pde file from the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is exactly the case: In the "website" home directory: processingjsversion-Folder; starter.html; starter.pde; In the processingjsversion Folder: processing.js and all the other files. Any other ideas why this does not work.

Comment: in your example you call it 'myname.pde', just now you call it starter.pde as it's listed in the directory. Your example matches what's on the page. You could also check your doctype

Comment: Thanks again. I checked for all the misspelled, directory etc errors. My problems is that it wont load. And I was wondering if there is anything other to do that is obvious and I missed. http.conf; correct Python; Do I need anything else. Does this example work with you? If yes, did you change anything. Sorry for the annoyance and Thanks for your time !